# iOS: TableView + Title for header in Section with image

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

It's the first time I'm trying to use TableView in iOS and have an issue.

I have a tableview just with 2 sections and two rows in each section.
I have a situation that I need to add an image above my first section of my tableview(something like adding a sign on top of the TableView) , I tried to create/add a headerView for the first section section,and embed my image in it, but the problem is the image doesn't let the title string for that section be shown. Do you think I need create & add (addsubview) another string as tile with UILable and append it to the headerView or is any other way to accomplish this?
The problem exists as long as I show the headerView for that section, as soon as I remove it, the section title will be appear.

Currently I do this in:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section    
{
    if (section == 0)
        return headerView;
    return nil;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
        return headerView.frame.size.height + self.rowHeight+28.0; //
    return 30.0;//for other title header section
}
```

and my headerView allocated like this:

```
CGRect headerViewRect = CGRectMake(0.0,  10.0,  frame.size.width -50  , self.rowHeight+50.0);
headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:headerViewRect];
headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIImageView *titleImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyTitlePicture.png"]] autorelease];
CGRect imageViewRect = CGRectMake(0.0,  0.0,  frame.size.width -100  , self.rowHeight+28.0);
titleImage.frame = imageViewRect;
titleImage.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
[headerView addSubview:titleImage];
```

TIA,
Kamran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you are replacing the default headerview, you are not adding to it. You need to program your UILabel and add that as a subview to your headerview.

Answer (score 1):

The tableView method (viewForHeaderInSection) should return your headerView (UIVIew*).
That code will return the header view for your section.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section    
{
if (section == 0){
    CGRect headerViewRect = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320,40);
    UIView* headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:headerViewRect];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIImageView *titleImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
          [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyTitlePicture.png"]] autorelease];
    CGRect imageViewRect = CGRectMake(0.0,  0.0, 320 , 40);
    titleImage.frame = imageViewRect;
    titleImage.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    [headerView addSubview:titleImage];

   //Then you can add a UILabel to your headerView
   return headerView;
}
return nil;
}
```